# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Set<string>' has no index signature

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I have following tsc:

```
tsc --version
Version 3.1.3
```

and tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "types": ["mocha", "node"],
    "typeRoots": [
      // add path to @types
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "rootDir": "./",
    "watch": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "typings/browser.d.ts", "typings/browser"]
}
```

and my sample code from documentation: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Iterators%20and%20Generators.md#forof-vs-forin-statements

```
function SymbolIterator() {
  let pets = new Set(["Cat", "Dog", "Hamster"]);
  pets["species"] = "mammals";

  for (let pet in pets) {
    console.log(pet); // "species"
  }     
  // "downlevelIteration": true (tsconfig.json)
  for (let pet of pets) {
    console.log(pet); // "Cat", "Dog", "Hamster"
  }
}

SymbolIterator();
```

tsc gives me following error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Set' has no
>   index signature.

I tried to change various compile settings but did not work. 
Is there any way to fix it in the code?

Error screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Sets are a like maps but they only store keys not key-value pairs. You are trying to use set as key vale pair.  'pets["species"] = "mammals";' is not possible through set you have to use map instead.

Comment: @GauravMoolani  you can store key-value in Sets => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Iterating_Sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example in the handbook is not about how to use sets. This line

```
pets["species"] = "mammals";
```

does not add anything to the set, it just sets `species` property on the set object. If you check for set membership with `pets.has("species")` after that, it will return `false`. In javascript, sets, as well as everything else, inherit from object, and you can set any property on any object in this way using `[]` notation.

The compiler gives you an error because you have specified more strict type checking with `--noImplicitAny` option. This option disallows accessing and setting undeclared object properties, so you can't add `species` property to set object in this way.

How to fix the code depends on what you want the code to do. If you want to compile it unmodified, you have to turn off `--noImplicitAny` option (or you can just ignore the error - the compiler generates javascript code anyway, unless you have `--noEmitOnError` option turned on).

Or you can declare `species` property for `pets` object, using [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types). It has to be optional because it's absent when object is created with `Set` constructor:

```
let pets: Set<string> & {species?: string} = new Set(["Cat", "Dog", "Hamster"]);

pets["species"] = "mammals"; // ok
// or simply
pets.species = "mammals";
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense. Actually error started to came out after upgrade to 3.x version. In 2.x version this was a valid example. Probably they should update the docs accordingly or mention about flags. Because I kept same tsconfig since then.

Answer (score 0):

Dear friend instead of using `for (let pet of pets)`
please use

```
 pets.forEach(r=>{ 
   console.log(r); // "Cat", "Dog", "Hamster"
 });
```